# Spring form binding - use IllegalArgumentException message as error message

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a custom domain class with a single constructor that takes a String, as well as a toString() method. The constructor decodes the input string, performs validations on it and throws IllegalArgumentException if invalid.

I want to bind directly to this field, as described here: http://blog.springsource.org/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/ (see 'Convention Over Configuration' section).

That is working fine & I am displaying the error message resolved by Spring (`typeMismatch on barcodeInfo`).

I know that I can customize this error message using a messageSource entry, e.g.

```
typeMismatch.barcodeInfo=Invalid format
```

**However, the error message that I want to display isn't always the same, it depends on the value of the input string**. Hence, I want to display the error message that I originally used in the IllegalArgumentException that I threw from the constructor. Is this possible?

I am specifically looking for a solution which will work with Spring WebFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check `BindingErrorProcessor` used by `WebDataBinder`. There you can implement your own custom logic for translating exceptions to validation errors.

---

Notes:

- You should implement your own exception (to be able to distinguish it from `IllegalArgumentException` thorwn by other components).
- You can initialize `WebDataBinder` with your custom `BindingErrorProcessor` within your `@InitBinder` method (or set specific `WebBindingInitializer` to your handler adapter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I updated the answer to specify that I am specifically looking for a solution for Spring WebFlow. Unfortunately, after more investigation, I don't think that it is possible. Hence, I'm accepting this answer, as it answers the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

As Pavel mentioned in his answer, you can achieve this by implementing `BindingErrorProcessor`.

It should look like this:

```
...
import org.springframework.validation.DefaultBindingErrorProcessor;
...

@Controller
public class YourController {

  ...

  @InitBinder
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setBindingErrorProcessor(new DefaultBindingErrorProcessor() {
      @Override
      public void processPropertyAccessException(
          PropertyAccessException ex, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (ex.getPropertyName().equals("fieldInQuestion")) {
          Throwable cause = ex.getMostSpecificCause();

          FieldError fieldError;
          fieldError = new FieldError(
            bindingResult.getObjectName(),
            "fieldInQuestion",
            cause.getMessage());

          bindingResult.addError(fieldError);
        } else {
          super.processPropertyAccessException(ex, bindingResult);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```